# Optimizing loop to find differences between two arrays with decile bucketing for heatmap plot

Tags: python, arrays, loops, optimization, machine-learning

Code was written before any plan to use it for many datafiles - lacks scalabiity

The problem: I have two arrays filled with prediction scores between 0 and 1. I want to compare the differences between two different model outputs, in a 10x10 heatmap. I get a score from the NNC model, and see how far off the corresponding instance is in the FLC, count the number and distribution of these differences, and then plot.

Things I have am considering/have been suggested by others:

1) turn arrays into pandas dataframes, potentially faster for bulk actions. Maybe use a progressively branching columns dataframe for each decile subset

2) create 10 individual arrays on the fly to partition values into decile buckets before looping

3) combine all the files into one array, so it will still take long but not overnight

4) replace some of the inline math operations with defining functions

For one file it takes ~80s to complete process, which is ok for one dataset but not 600 unless I want to run overnight. This is the cell that takes longest:
(code has been modified a bit to let it be run by itself)

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

startTime = time.time()

fromNNC = 0
toNNC = 0.1
fromDC = 0
toDC = 0.1

comparisonNNC = np.random.rand(14044, 1)
comparisonFLC = np.random.rand(14044, 1)

diffGridC = np.array([])
diffGridCounterC = 0

thisDiffC = 0

for yaxis in range(10):        
    for xaxis in range(10):
        for eachScore in range(len(comparisonNNC)):
            if(comparisonNNC[eachScore] > fromNNC and comparisonNNC[eachScore] < toNNC):
                thisDiffC = (abs(comparisonNNC[eachScore] - comparisonFLC[eachScore]))
                #print(thisDiff)
                if(thisDiffC > fromDC and thisDiffC < toDC):
                    diffGridCounterC = diffGridCounterC + 1

        diffGridC = np.append(diffGridC, diffGridCounterC)
        diffGridCounterC = 0

        fromDC = fromDC + 0.1
        #print(fromNN)
        toDC = toDC + 0.1
        #print(toNN)    

    fromDC = 0.0
    toDC = 0.1

    fromNNC = fromNNC + 0.1
    toNNC = toNNC + 0.1
    print(fromNNC)    


diffGridC = diffGridC.reshape(10, 10)
diffGridC = diffGridC.astype(int)
print(diffGridC.shape)

diffMapC = sns.heatmap(diffGridC, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap="OrRd")
diffMapC.set(xlabel='Diff', ylabel='NN')
plt.xticks(range(10), ['0.0-0.1', '0.1-0.2', '0.2-0.3', '0.3-0.4', '0.4-0.5',
                       '0.5-0.6', '0.6-0.7', '0.7-0.8', '0.8-0.9', '0.9-1.0'], rotation=50)
plt.yticks(range(10), ['0.0-0.1', '0.1-0.2', '0.2-0.3', '0.3-0.4', '0.4-0.5',
                       '0.5-0.6', '0.6-0.7', '0.7-0.8', '0.8-0.9', '0.9-1.0'], rotation=0)
plt.show()

#diffGridDFC = pd.DataFrame(diffGridC)
#diffGridDFC.to_csv('difference grid correct.csv')  

endTime = time.time()
print(endTime - startTime)
```

Output looks like:[Heatmap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qVQSA.png)

Edit: attempted zipping the arrays, didnt improve the speed by much at all

```
for eachScoreNNC, eachScoreFLC in zip(comparisonNNC, comparisonFLC):
    if(eachScoreNNC > fromNNC and eachScoreNNC < toNNC):
        thisDiffC = (abs(eachScoreNNC - eachScoreFLC))
        #print(thisDiff)
```

Any suggestions experts here have in mind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED], thanks to /u/two_bob on /r/learnpython

Created buckets for both arrays that are to be compared, and then used groupby to count the intersections - then used dropin method into the heatmap grid instead of looping/searching through all 100 cells for matches.

```
    correctNNFL['NNbuckets'] = pd.cut(correctNNFL['Score'], np.linspace(0, 1, 11), labels=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'])
    correctNNFL['difference'] = abs(correctNNFL['Score'] - correctNNFL['Conf. Perc Uncreditworthy'])
    correctNNFL['diffBuckets'] = pd.cut(correctNNFL['difference'], np.linspace(0, 1, 11), labels=['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9'])

    correctNNFL.groupby(['diffBuckets']).count()
    diffCoords = np.array(correctNNFL[['NNbuckets', 'diffBuckets']].groupby(['diffBuckets', 'NNbuckets'])['diffBuckets'].count().index.tolist())
    diffIntersections = correctNNFL[['NNbuckets', 'diffBuckets']].groupby(['diffBuckets', 'NNbuckets'])['diffBuckets'].count().as_matrix()

    diffGridC = np.zeros(100)
    #diffGridC = np.arange(100)
    diffGridC = diffGridC.reshape(10, 10)
    diffGridC = diffGridC.astype(int)

    for eachBucket in range(len(diffCoords)):
        diffGridC[int(diffCoords[eachBucket][1])][int(diffCoords[eachBucket][0])] = int(diffIntersections[eachBucket])
    print(diffGridC)
    diffMapC = sns.heatmap(diffGridC, annot=True, fmt='d', cmap="OrRd")
    diffMapC.set(xlabel='Diff', ylabel='NN')
    plt.show()
```